# How to get today 00:00 time

Tags: c#

how can I get today datetime from 00:00, for example when I Use:

```
var dt=DateTime.Now; // 2019/1/1 15:22:22
```

I need Another extention method to give this string format:

```
string today = dt.TodayBegining(); // 2019/1/1 00:00:00
```

Comment: You mean `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: `string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/M/d");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
DateTime.Today
```

Doc: [DateTime.Today Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netframework-4.8)

*An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.*